# Illegal argument error: logits and labels must be same size, batch size is different

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using CNN to classifies MNIST dataset into 10 classes.
But the error shows the batch size of the pred is different.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[36,10] labels_size=[64,10]
         [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_2, Reshape_3)]]
```

I can't find the reason why the batch size became 36 instead of 64.
Here is my code. The image size is 28*28*1.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# input data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/data/', one_hot=True)
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./MNIST_data', one_hot=True)  # runing on server

learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 200000
batch_size = 64
display_step = 10

n_input = 784
n_classes = 10
dropout = 0.75

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # dropout


def conv2d(name, x, W, b, s=1):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, s, s, 1], padding='SAME'))

def maxpool2d(name, x, k=2, s=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, s, s, 1],
                          padding='VALID', name=name)

def norm(name, l_input, lsize=4):
    return tf.nn.lrn(l_input, lsize, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0,
                     beta=0.75, name=name)


def alex_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    conv1 = conv2d('conv1', x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'], s=1)  
    pool1 = maxpool2d('pool1', conv1, k=2, s=2) 
    norm1 = norm('norm1', pool1)

    conv2 = conv2d('conv2', norm1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'], s=1)
    pool2 = maxpool2d('pool2', conv2, k=2, s=2)
    norm2 = norm('norm2', pool2)

    conv3 = conv2d('conv3', norm2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'], s=1)
    pool3 = maxpool2d('pool3', conv3, k=2, s=2)
    norm3 = norm('norm3', pool3)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(norm3, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

    fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd2']), biases['bd2'])
    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)

    out = tf.matmul(fc2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out


weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 64])),
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 128])),
    'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 256])),

    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4*4*256, 1024])),
    'wd2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256])),

    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'bd2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


pred = alex_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)


cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))



init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                 keep_prob: dropout})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                    y: batch_y,
                                                    keep_prob: 1.})
            print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                   y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                   keep_prob: 1.}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be because the padding used for `maxpool2d` is 'VALID' instead of 'SAME'. How it affected the batch layer was due to reshaping `fc1 = tf.reshape(norm3, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])`

If the above answer didn't correct the error, you should check the output shape of each function by running `function_name.eval(sess, feed_dict = {x: mnist.test.images[:256], y: mnist.test.labels[:256], keep_prob: 1.})).shape` in your terminal and see what is the output shape, and whether it is the desired shape for that layer.

Comment: Thanks, it works after change 'VALID' to 'SAME'. But according to my understanding, setting `maxpool2d` is 'VALID' only will reshape the image shape, not the batch size. For example, if my input is 28*28, after the using the maxpool with kernel size is 2 and stride is 2, the output size should be `(28 - 2) / 2 + 1 = 14`. But if set padding is 'SAME', I thought the output size will still be 28 instead of 14. Now I know my understanding is wrong, but I am a little confused with this. Could you give me a more clear explanation?

Comment: Indeed, 'VALID' and 'SAME' does not change the batch size, but they change the length and height of the image. 'SAME' adds sufficient padding  to each image such that the resulting maxpool will have half the size of the original. (E.g. 28x28 to 14x14) 'VALID' does not add padding, and the size of the output is smaller dependent on the stride, if I'm not wrong. Hence using valid causes the output size to be smaller than 14x14.

Comment: Why the batch size was affected was due to the reshaping of `fc1`. The features were smaller than 4*4*256 because of using 'VALID' padding, but the reshape was [-1, 4*4*256,1024], so the batch is compromised

Comment: Thanks, I figure out why I get the batch size wrong.